# How to use if statement to add color overlay in FFMPEG

Tags: if-statement, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y -t 10 -vf drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=200:h=200:color='if(1==1\,red\,green)':t=fill output.mp4
```

I tried to test how can I use if statement to add colored square overlay to a video, but got following error.

Cannot find color 'if(1==1,red,green)'
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002d24a659440] Error initializing filter 'drawbox' with args 'x=0:y=0:w=200:h=200:color=if(1==1,red,green):t=fill'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of FFmpeg on Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Expression-Evaluation) equality should be tested with `eq(x,y)`, here is what the doc says:

> eq(x, y)
> Return 1 if x and y are equivalent, 0 otherwise.

This might be for testing purposes but I have to mention that `if(eq(1\,1)\,red\,green)` will always return `red`.

> if(x, y, z)
> Evaluate x, and if the result is non-zero return the evaluation result of y, otherwise the evaluation result of z.